# Java turning a String into a 10x10 two dimensional array

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a String that is 100 characters long seperated by a "." into a two dimensional array 
The String that has to be changed basically looks something like this XXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX.XXX...

Comment: Use String#split to turn into a 1D array of strings at first. Then turn those strings into arrays themselves using Java streams

Comment: Have you tried anything yet or researched? Note that you are required to do that before posting at SO, hence the downvotes. Also, what exactly do you mean by "turn into a two dimensional array", what logic should that follow exactly? Your question is unclear, a concrete and simple example would really help.

Comment: The String is basically a representation of some kind of game board, where each character in the String is some kind of field. The dots indicate the next row of the board.

Answer (score 1):

You can use String split() functionality and inside a split function you pass a dot as an argument, so you will end up having a single array where each slot will contain certain quantity of characters